# iPhone: Using MFMailComposeViewController API image problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController API in iPhone app to send images via Email.

It displays correctly on iPhone but fails to show the image in Computer.

When we click that image on computer it shows "no preview available".

We are using PNG images.

What could be wrong?

**Code:**

```
  NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:FilePath]

  [emailAPIObject addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Image"];
```

Comment: can you post the rest of the mail composer method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this code working with small changes:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataContentsOfFile:FilePath];   
[emailAPIObject addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"png" fileName:@"Image.png"];
```

Comment: Does this code enable us to download images when the email is opened in Computer?

Comment: Yep, image will be added as an attachment and also inserted into the mail body.

Comment: ok dats fine. I will try out this code very soon and get back to you.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Still it shows "No Preview Available" when I click the attached image in email from my computer. Are you sure this is the way to do it?